# Using variable counter value within UPDATE statement - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

Working with following code:

```
UPDATE Roster
SET Absences = Absences + 1
WHERE ID = 1234
```

I understand this will add 1 to the numeric value of 'Absences', but believe I must repeat this Update each time student '1234' is Absent.

Can I replace 'Absences + 1' with a Variable (perhaps 'Count') that references an external function that counts Absences. If so, how might I accomplish this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  Absences INT
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 5);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 6);

CREATE TABLE test2 (
  id INT,
  count INT
);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1, 0);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (2, 3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
UPDATE test
SET Absences = (select max(count) from test2 where id = 2)
WHERE id = 2;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from test;
```

| id | Absences |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qv1fVtYWKWNz4FmjCrhedz/0)